# Play Audio File from uri when recyclerview item is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm working to make a music player app. I have showed all of the songs in the recyclerview, now I'm wondering how can I start playing music files when I click on recyclerview items.
Here's what I have:

```
 @Override
    public void OnTrackClick(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), MediaPlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("clicked", trackList.get(position));
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(trackList.get(position).getTrackArtist()));
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(uri.toString());
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can someone gives me a hint?

Comment: If that works then why do you need a hint?

Comment: if it works why do I need to ask?